# Creating a ClickOnce deployment for an existing application

Tags: clickonce, powerbuilder, mage

I have an application which I would like to deploy using [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce). I've tried using `mage.exe` and `ClickOnceMore` and can't get it to work. I don't understand the instructions for `Mage`, and with `ClickOnceMore` I get an `MSB3171 error`:

```
problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly
'u:\users\...\local\temp\CmDepBuildDir\[application].exe'
or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a
program with an incorrect format.
```

We have been using this application for a long time, but we need a new method to deploy it to users. It isn't a [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) application; the base program is [PowerBuilder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerBuilder). It has an `.exe` file, some `.pbd` files and a few `.dlls` which make up the program. Is it possible to create a ClickOnce deployment for this type of application?

Comment: No, you can't: "If you app is  ... an unmanaged code executable, then no, you cannot deploy it as an executable through ClickOnce. The MAGE tool takes a look at the executable that you select as the entry point for the application, and won't let you specify an unmanaged executable as the entry point. Without an entry point, you don't have a valid launchable ClickOnce application." http://www.softinsight.com/bnoyes/2005/04/05/DeployingAndLaunchingNonWhidbeyAppsWithClickOnce.aspx

Comment: Thank you, that is pretty clear. I'll see if Brian Noyes' workarounds will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about PowerBuilder, but you might want to look into WiX. It might be possible to deploy your application with ClickOnce, but I'm pretty sure that ClickOnce is part of the .NET framework. WiX has a bit of a learning curve, but it is a powerful tool if you want to create an installer for your application.

http://wixtoolset.org/

http://dotupdater.codeplex.com/

Comment: Well, this is not quite the right solution. I need to deploy the program with some method which will check the master file for updates to the program, to make sure users have the latest version. So I'm not sure WiX will help with that.

Comment: You could look into ClickThrough, which is part of WiX, though I have no experience with it and hear that it is not really ready yet. Also, you could take a look at the link to DotUpdater that I just added in my post. Again, I have no experience with it, but it sounds like it may do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used ClickOnce myself, but ClickOnce is supposed to work with PowerBuilder [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) applications. (PowerBuilder Classic can create Windows Forms applications.)

Theoretically, you could just add a Windows Forms target to your current application's workspace and base the target off your existing application. You could keep working on your application the old way and then when you're ready to publish you would build the Windows Forms target instead. Then apply whatever needs to be done for ClickOnce.

Of course, that's all theory. Reality may be a little different.

You can read more about it in *[Smart Client Application Development Using PowerBuilder 11.0](http://pbdj.sys-con.com/node/297705?page=0,0)*.